# Unable to Install expo-cli

Tags: node.js, expo

Unable to perform npm install -g expo-cli
OS : MACOS
Tried running the command with sudo user
Getting below exception.

````
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! libxmljs@0.19.7 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --loglevel http`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the libxmljs@0.19.7 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/root/.npm/_logs/2019-11-17T17_36_58_769Z-debug.log```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `npm i -g expo-cli@3.5.0`

I also had the same error with latest version of Expo, but 3.5.0 version installs without problem.